# Difference between cat 5 and 6 patch panel?

Tags: networking

What's the physical difference between category 5 and 6 patch panel? Do the connectors are different? Why they are more expensive? Can I use cat. 5 rated patch panel with category 6 cabling? I'm talking about unshielded network.

Answer (score 6):

Read [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_6#Category_6) section.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the two are that one has better shielding than the other and has been tested to higher specifications (up to 10 Gbit / s)

Comment: +1 Refer Chopper3's answer for the link to the Wikipedia technical details.

Answer (score 1):

NO! cat6 cable with cat6 connectors = cat6 but cat6 cable + cat5 connectors = not cat6 or cat5 will it work maybe but it is certainly not the right way of doing things. choose cat5 or cat6 and make everything match.